# can i have aspectj for Camel Component(marshal and unMarshal)?

Tags: apache-camel, marshalling, aspectj, execution, unmarshalling

i tried to have aspectj for camel processor, but it is not working. My pointcut is below:

```java
@Around("execution(* org.apache.camel.processor.UnmarshalProcessor.*(..))")
```

Will it possible to do aspect for camel processor?? if yes, help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can if you put the library on the *inpath* in a compile-time weaving scenario, creating modified versions of the 3rd party class files and using them during runtime.

In a load-time weaving scenario you can also do it dynamically if the weaving agent is loaded before the *Camel* classes, which should usually be the case.

As a work-around you can change the pointcut type from `execution()` to `call()`, intercepting the callers in your own code rather than the callee in the 3rd party library.

So you have at least three options, all of which work with AspectJ (not in an "AOP lite" variant like Spring AOP though).